# Loop Python NLTK classifier through a list of tweets

Tags: python, for-loop, twitter, nltk

I have trained a NaiveBaynes classifier using the twitter_sample corpus. I was able to test the classifier on one tweet in order to ensure it works. However, I am trying to now loop the classifier through a list of ~4000 tweets and am getting an AttributeError on my code:

```
test_sample = []
for (words, sentiment) in test_tweets:
     words_filtered = [t.lower() for t in words.split() if len(t) >= 3]
     sentiment = classifier.classify(extract_features(words.split()))
     test_sample.append(words_filtered, sentiment)

AttributeError: 'list' object has not attribute 'split'
```

test_tweets is a list of tweets that have this structure:

```
('blah tweety blah', 'tbd')
```

I'm performing sentiment analysis on the tweets and the classifier produces a **pos** or **neg** result for each tweet yielding an output like this:

```
('blah tweety blah', 'pos')
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my loop?

Comment: `split()` is a method used on a string object. Are you sure `words` is a string and not a list? You can check using the `type()` function.

Comment: ```words``` is a list and not a string thus that was the issue. Sorry for not checking that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That attribute error means you are trying to split a list - so test_tweets does not have the format you think it does. There must be a list where you are expecting a string.

As a troubleshooting step, you can temporarily modify your loop to find the words which are lists instead of string:

```
test_sample = []
for (words, sentiment) in test_tweets:
    if type(words) is list:
        print('This is a list, not a string ', end='') 
        print(words)
     # words_filtered = [t.lower() for t in words.split() if len(t) >= 3]
     # sentiment = classifier.classify(extract_features(words.split()))
     # test_sample.append(words_filtered, sentiment)
```

Then once you identify which words are lists, you have a few options. You can use the same if statement to either skip that set of data or clean it up.

```
test_sample = []
for (words, sentiment) in test_tweets:
    if type(words) is list:
        words_filtered = [t.lower() for t in words if len(t) >= 3] # just skip the split method
        sentiment = classifier.classify(extract_features(words))
        # continue  if you want to skip over lists, you can use continue to go to the next iteration of the loop
    else:
        words_filtered = [t.lower() for t in words.split() if len(t) >= 3]
        sentiment = classifier.classify(extract_features(words.split()))
    test_sample.append(words_filtered, sentiment)
```